# Can a Windows 10 UWP (Desktop Bridge) app re-launch its own executable?

Tags: windows, uwp, desktop-bridge

I have created a UWP app for Windows 10 using the Desktop Bridge. Mostly it works just fine, however my app needs to re-launch its own executable (with different command-line arguments). The two processes work together.

This works just fine for the non-UWP app, but when run as a UWP, I can't seem to re-launch my own executable (as derived from the process command-line). Should this be possible? Is there a particular way that I need to do it an UWP app?

Currently I get the error: **Access is denied.**

Answer (score 2):

To launch your app the same way it would be launched when the user taps the app list entry, you can do this:

```
private async void StartMyApp()
{
    var appListEntries = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.GetAppListEntriesAsync();
    await appListEntries.First().LaunchAsync();
}
```

This code assumes your package manifest contains only one application node. In case you have multiple, you need to pick the right one to call LaunchAsync on.